# How to append to array in C

Tags: arrays, c, append, c-strings

Let's say I have an empty array that will be filled with strings, how do I then append a string to it when I want to?

Here is what I have so far.

```
string people[20] = {};

string name = "james";

strcpy(people[0], name);
```

Comment: Use `strcat` to append to the end of an existing null-terminated string.

Comment: Also, you need to allocate space for `people[0]` before you can store to it.  Remember, `string` in `cs50` is nothing more than a `typedef` for `char *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account your code snippet

```
string people[20] = {};

string name = "james";

strcpy(people[0], name);
```

it seems that the type `string` is defined like

```
typedef char * string;
```

So this declaration

```
string people[20] = {};
```

declares an array of elements of the type `char *`.

You may not use as an initializer empty braces. You need to write at least like

```
string people[20] = { NULL };
```

So to add an element to the array you should write

```
people[0] = name;
```

Or without using an intermediate variable

```
people[0] = "james";
```

Another approach is to allocate a memory dynamically for an element of the array and copy in the memory a string. For example

```
people[0] = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
strcpy( people[0], name );
```

Answer (score 1):

CS50 strikes again.

Be aware that in the process of making C somewhat easier to use, the CS50 library *grossly* misrepresents how strings and string processing actually work in C.  The `string` type is not a native C type - it's a typedef name (alias) for the type "pointer to `char`" (`char *`).  A CS50 `string` doesn't actually store a *string* (a sequence of characters), it stores the *address* of the first character of a string.  That means that

```
string people[20];
```

isn't actually an array of *strings*, it's an array of *pointers*:

```
char *people[20];
```

In C, a string is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator - the string `"hello"` is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  All strings (including string literals) are stored as *arrays* of character type (`char` for ASCII/EBCDIC/UTF-8, `wchar_t` for "wide" encodings).

Under most circumstances, array expressions "decay" to pointer expressions<sup>1</sup>, so most of the time when we're working with strings we are working with pointers expressions, but a pointer is not a string.

If you want to append multiple strings together into a single string, such as

```
"foo" + "bar" == "foobar"
```

then you would need to do the following:

```
/**
 * Create a target buffer large enough to store the final string. In
 * this case we need a buffer 7 elements wide - 6 for the characters
 * "foobar" plus 1 for the string terminator.  The initial contents of
 * this array are *indeterminate*:
 *
 * +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 * | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? |
 * +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 */
char target[7]; 

/**
 * Copy the string "foo" to the target buffer.  After this operation,
 * the target buffer will contain:
 *
 * +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 * |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 | ? | ? | ? |
 * +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 */
strcpy( target, "foo" ); 

/**
 * Append "bar" to the end of the string in target - looks for the 
 * string terminator, and starts appending at that point.  After 
 * this operation the target array should contain:
 *
 * +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 * |'f'|'o'|'o'|'b'|'a'|'r'| 0 |
 * +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 */
strcat( target, "bar" );
```

If you want to create an *array* of strings (which is what it looks like you're asking for), then you will either need to create a 2D array of `char`:

```
char strings[NUM_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
```

and then use `strcpy` to copy string contents:

```
strcpy( strings[0], "foo" );
strcpy( strings[1], "bar" );
strcpy( strings[2], "bletch" );
```

giving you something like

```
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+     +---+
strings[0] |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 | ? | ? | ? | ... | ? |
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+     +---+
strings[1] |'b'|'a'|'r'| 0 | ? | ? | ? | ... | ? |
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+     +---+
strings[2] |'b'|'l'|'e'|'t'|'c'|'h'| 0 | ... | ? |
           +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+     +---+
```

Or you will need to create an array of pointers (which is what you have in your code) and then store the *address* of each string:

```
char *strings[NUM_STRINGS];

strings[0] = "foo";
strings[1] = "bar";
strings[2] = "bletch";
```

which gives you something like

```
            +---+                               +---+
strings[0]: |   | ----------------------------> |'f'|
            +---+                      +---+    +---+
strings[1]: |   | -------------------> |'b'|    |'o'|
            +---+             +---+    +---+    +---+
strings[2]: |   | ----------> |'b'|    |'a'|    |'o'|
            +---+             +---+    +---+    +---+
             ...              |'l'|    |'r'|    | 0 |
                              +---+    +---+    +---+
                              |'e'|    | 0 |     ...
                              +---+    +---+
                              |'t'|     ...
                              +---+
                              |'c'|
                              +---+
                              |'h'|
                              +---+
                              | 0 |
                              +---+
                               ...
```

Be aware that string literals may not be writable - the behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined*. Your code *might* crash, it might behave as expected, it might corrupt other data, or it might do something else completely.  If you have something like

```
char *strings[20];
...
strings[0] = "joe";
```

then you can set `strings[0]` to point to a different string literal, like so:

```
strings[0] = "bob";
```

but if you try to modify the *contents* of the literal that `strings[0]` points to:

```
strcpy( strings[0], "bob" );
```

then your code may not behave as expected.  However, if you create an array and initialize it with a string:

```
char *strings[20];
char name[] = "joe";

strings[0] = name; // assigning the *address* of name[0] to strings[0]
strcpy( strings[0], "bob" );
```

then this will work as expected, since `strings[0]` points to `name`, which is a writable buffer.  But `name` can only store names up to 3 characters long, so if you try to do something like

```
strcpy( strings[0], "aloysius" );
```

you'll write past the end of the `names` array and clobber anything following it.

Yes, string processing in C is a major PITA, which is why the CS50 library tries to gloss over it.  But again, in doing so, they misrepresent how things actually work, and are setting students up for failure when they have to deal with C strings on their own.

---

1. Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize an array of character type in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.